# R: adding a legend to a density plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, data-visualization, legend

I am working with the R programming language. I am following this tutorial here on density plots: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/2d-density-plot-with-ggplot2.html

I am trying to figure out how to add a "legend" to the density plots, so that the user can see roughly how many observations are located within a given region of the density plot.

I was able to figure out how to do this for a basic plot (by following the tutorial) :

```
#load library
library(ggplot2)

#create data
a <- data.frame( x=rnorm(20000, 10, 1.9), y=rnorm(20000, 10, 1.2) )
b <- data.frame( x=rnorm(20000, 14.5, 1.9), y=rnorm(20000, 14.5, 1.9) )
c <- data.frame( x=rnorm(20000, 9.5, 1.9), y=rnorm(20000, 15.5, 1.9) )
data <- rbind(a,b,c)

#make density plot
ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y) ) +
  geom_bin2d(bins = 70) +
  scale_fill_continuous(type = "viridis") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

As seen in the above plot, a legend has been automatically created ("count").

But when I try to do this for the other plots in the tutorial, no legends are added:

```
# plot 1
ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y) ) +
  stat_density_2d(aes(fill = ..density..), geom = "raster", contour = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette=4, direction=-1) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme(
    legend.position='none'
  )
 
# plot 2
ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y) ) +
  stat_density_2d(aes(fill = ..density..), geom = "raster", contour = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette=4, direction=1) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme(
    legend.position='none'
  )
 
# plot 3
ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y) ) +
  stat_density_2d(aes(fill = ..density..), geom = "raster", contour = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette= "Spectral", direction=1) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme(
    legend.position='none'
  )
```

[image]

Can someone please show me if it is possible to add legends to these plots?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried removing the `legend.position = 'none'` theme setting?

Comment: thank you! you have solved the problem!